# Tomcat 7.0 -Spring MVC, jpa Crud application - The origin server did notfindacurrent rep for the target resource in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa

I refered the [youtube link](https://youtu.be/bc7NIVJEdb4) to learn spring,MYSQl,JSP for CRUD Application.I tried as per the video.. and i have created all the model,view and controller classes.

> I'm using to code with Eclipse in UBUNTU 16.04

**Github Source Code link:**
[Link](https://github.com/varuncbv/SPRING-MYSQL-JSP-CRUD-APPLICATION)

I have some errors that is,

**Error Screenshot:**
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9x6ne.png)